# Is there a name for the outer-most path on a binary tree, from root to leaf?

Tags: data-structures, tree, binary-tree, graph-theory

I'm looking for a term that refers to the outer-most edges of the path that traverses a tree from the root to the left-most leaf. So the algorithm to find that path is just to take the left-most child recursively until you hit the leaf, and aggregate the nodes. I was thinking about using 'flank', or 'outside edges' or something, but I feel like there's gotta be a technical term for this. Please help!

Comment: I haven't come across the term for it so far in my career. we used to call it the `left border`.

Comment: Maybe Left view of a binary tree.

Comment: There are questions like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30275735/to-print-the-boundary-of-binary-tree (and many others) that ask about printing the boundary of a tree. So I would be tempted to call what you're asking about the `left boundary`.

Comment: Thank you! I think Left View is the technical term (see here one of the top google results for [printing a left view](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-left-view-binary-tree/)). That is what I want, although my trees would never have a levelin which the left-most node of a level is not the child of the left-most node of the previous level.  Should work fine though. Either way I've got 3 great options. Thanks!